# Read Flex/Flash URL which has Transfer-Encoding chunked

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, apache, chunked

I have a problem reading from Flex a url which has Transfer-Encoding: chunked because the FLex waits for the server to send terminate signal which in chunked transfer isn't sent...

Answer (score 0):

Use the URLStream class instead of whatever loader you're using now.  Its ProgressEvents will let you read chunks before the message completes.

Answer (score -1):

But if you read the documents a little more carefully, you will find the following. So it becomes clear, you just need to check the size of received chunks until it get ZERO.

> The data transfer is terminated by a
>   final chunk of length zero

Comment: Not helpful.  The problem is not how to terminate the chunked response, it's how to get the Flex API to provide access to the response before it's been terminated by the server.

(This is a good way to stream data from server to client over HTTP, but it requires the client APIs to provide access to the response data prior to the stream being terminated.  Apparently the Flex API doesn't do this... at least not by default.  Hence the OP's question about how to make it do that.)