# AsyncContext works with JSP and not with flex

Tags: apache-flex, servlet-3.0

I am implementing Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext in Tomcat Version:7.0.11
To test this a simple servlet was developed which pushed data over a async context

Server:
The servlet takes a number as input, sleeps for 4 seconds, sends the square of the number as an update to client via the async context 
This square of previously sent result is sent for four times before the async context's complete method is called.

Client:
The sample client is a jsp file which does the POST with the number as input.
The async replies are just printed on to the browser.
All is well till this stage.

Change of client:
Without changing the server code, I changed the client to Flex.
The same post method is called with the number as input.
And there is a TextArea flash component to print the received replies.

The async replies are not getting printed  as and when then they are received but all of them gets printed after the last async reply is received.
(I can see that replies are chunked and they are received in the browser via IE's F12-Developer tool)

Is there a way I can get the intermediate async replies to get printed in the Flex client (without using BlazeDS or LifeCycle or GraniteDS and the like)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using HTTPService for sending requests from Flex, I used URLStream and used the ProgressEvent to print the intermediate chunked data and it worked.

Thanks to @Justin who has replied to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568168/read-flex-flash-url-which-has-transfer-encodingchunked)